# "Expected 2 placeholders. Given 1" error when creating an AWS QuickSight Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have setup a template.json file as suggested in the AWS Quicksight documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/evolve-your-analytics-with-amazon-quicksights-new-apis-and-theming-capabilities/). My file looks like this:

```
{
"AwsAccountId": "xxxxxxx",
"TemplateId": "TestTemplate",
"Name": "Demo Dashboard Template",
"SourceEntity": {
    "SourceAnalysis": {
        "Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:xxx:analysis/xxxxxx
        "DataSetReferences": [
            {
                "DataSetPlaceholder": "Test",
                "DataSetArn": "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:xxxx:dataset/xxxxx$
            }
        ]
    }
},
"VersionDescription": "1"
```

}

When I call the following command as instructed:

`aws quicksight --region us-east-1 create-template --cli-input-json file://./template.json`

I get the following error:
`An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateTemplate operation: Expected 2 placeholders. Given 1`

What's causing the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have one data set in your analysis or more? You need to include all of them. I had the same error when I had multiple datasets but I only included one of them.