# What is the right AWS Quicksight Template Schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Questions related to this post :
["Expected 2 placeholders. Given 1" error when creating an AWS QuickSight Template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63799513/17615596)
[Creating a template with multiple data sets using the QuickSight API, from Python 3/boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65348698/17615596)

I'm facing an issue with the AWS QuickSight template skeleton format.
I can't find how to write the file when my analysis has 2 or more datasets.

Here's the only example I could find from the AWS docs, followed by what I tried.
I attempted another way to write the dataSetReferences without success.

Example :

```
{
  "SourceAnalysis": {
    "Arn": "string",
    "DataSetReferences": [
      {
        "DataSetPlaceholder": "string",
        "DataSetArn": "string"
      }
      ...
    ]
  },
  "SourceTemplate": {
    "Arn": "string"
  }
}
```

I tried

```
{
"AwsAccountId": "91********43",
"TemplateId": "my-template-analysis-id",
"Name": "my-template-analysis-name",
"SourceEntity": {
    "SourceAnalysis": {
        "Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight:eu-west-1:91********43:analysis/12******-***-****-****-******ef",
        "DataSetReferences": [
            {
                "DataSetPlaceholder": "datasetname1",
                "DataSetArn": "arn:aws:quicksight:eu-west-1:91********43:dataset/fd******-***-****-****-******e6"
            },
            {
                "DataSetPlaceholder": "datasetname2",
                "DataSetArn": "arn:aws:quicksight:eu-west-1:91********43:dataset/2d******-***-****-****-******cb"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"VersionDescription": "1"
}
```

[See API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG8aM.png)

Answer (score 1):

The json file is actually well written in the example.
I just had a typing error in my file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).